# Erro de versão ao anexar banco de dados sql server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015

Estou tentando anexar um banco de dados de um arquivo .mdf gerado pelo visual Studio, na hora que criei o banco de dados identity, porem estou tentando anexar esse banco de dados no `sql server` e esta dando um erro de incompatibilidade de versão [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço pra anexar este banco?

> Obs; já atualizei meu sql server e não resolveu.

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente está tentando restaurar um backup de uma versão superior em um SQL Server com versão inferior, por exemplo, seu backup é do SQL Server 2014 e está tentando fazer o restore no SQL Server 2008.